# Why aren't my css sprites working?

Tags: html, css

```
#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a {
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/social_media.png') no-repeat;
    height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
}
#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.twitter {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.twitter:hover {
    background-position: 0 - 35;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.facebook {
    background-position: -35 0;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.facebook:hover {
    background-position: -35 - 35;
}


#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.be {
    background-position: -70 0;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.be:hover {
    background-position: -70 - 35;
}
```

this is my css code, but when I view the page, it just show's the a.twitter always, nothing happens when I hover, it just stays a.twitter. for a.facebook also it shows a.twitter e.c.

Here is the html code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header background starts -->
        <div id="header"></div>
        <!-- Header Background ends -->
        <!-- Middle content starts -->
        <div id="border">
            <!-- Header Wrapper starts -->
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <!-- Header upper Part starts -->
                <div id="header-wrapper-upper">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Season Logo" title="Season logo" id="logo" />
                    <div id="social-top">
                        <a href="#" class="twitter">&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="#" class="facebook">&nbsp;</a>
                        <a href="#" class="be">&nbsp;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Header upper Part ends -->
            </div>
            <!-- Header Wrapper Ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- Middle Content ends -->
    </body>
</html>
```

any clues? First time using sprites, so I'm not quite sure. Nothing show's up in console either.

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kEQUw/

Comment: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.
for sprites reference [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 'px' to background-position

ex.

1. 0 -35px
2. 0 0
3. 0 35px...and so on.

Comment: And remove the spaces after the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Are there really spaces between the minus sign and 35, in the CSS? Did you check the CSS and HTML in a validator?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. Because the way [your sprite](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg546/scaled.php?server=546&filename=socialmedia.png&res=landing) is built (with spaces between the icons) you could use the [spritecow online tool](http://www.spritecow.com/) to get the correct values of each element of the sprite.

So your correct code should be:

```
#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a {
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/social_media.png') no-repeat;
    height: 32px; /* not 35 */
    width: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; /* NEW */
}
#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.twitter {
    background-position: -2px -3px;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.twitter:hover {
    background-position: -2px -38px;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.facebook {
    background-position: -52px -2px;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.facebook:hover {
    background-position: -52px -37px;
}


#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.be {
    background-position: -103px -2px;
}

#border #header-wrapper #header-wrapper-upper #social-top a.be:hover {
    background-position: -103px -37px;
}
```